# How to establish a connection through microsoft sql server using code behind?

Tags: asp.net, connection-string, code-behind

I am having a problem with my asp.net project setting up a connection to the ms sql server. 
Here's my aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="OnlineAppSyss.aspx.cs" Inherits="SoftwareAnalysisAndDesign.SAD.OnlineAppSyss" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Online AppSyss System</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#339966">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Welcome to Online AppSess System</h1>
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <input type="text" id="Username" runat="server" placeholder="Username" />
                <input type="text" id="Password" runat="server" placeholder="Password" />
                <button type="submit" id="login-button" onserverclick="Button1_Click">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="bg-bubbles">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And my aspx code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SoftwareAnalysisAndDesign.SAD
{
    public partial class OnlineAppSyss : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public class MSConnector
        {
            public String ConnectionString { get; set; }
            public DataSet ExecuteQuery(String sqlStatement)
            {
                try
                {

                    DataSet results = new DataSet();

                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                    {
                        if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                        }

                        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStatement, conn))
                        {
                            da.Fill(results);
                        }

                        if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
                            conn.Close();
                        }
                    }

                    return results;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }

        public static string query = null;
        private DataSet selectedData;
        private DataTable dt;
        private MSConnector connector = new MSConnector();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Login();
        }
        public void Login()
        {
            //ConnectionString for accessing into MSSql
            connector.ConnectionString = "SERVER=KEITH;UID=KEITH/LaurenceKeith;Password=;DATABASE=Student;";

            string username = (this.Username.Value);
            string password = (this.Password.Value);

            if (username == "" && password == "")
            {
                query = "select * from Student where StudentID = 2011017997'";
                query = "select * from Student where Password = 'lalbano' '";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

this is my code for setting up a connection using this class MSConnector

```
public class MSConnector
        {
            public String ConnectionString { get; set; }
            public DataSet ExecuteQuery(String sqlStatement)
            {
                try
                {

                    DataSet results = new DataSet();

                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                    {
                        if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                        }

                        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStatement, conn))
                        {
                            da.Fill(results);
                        }

                        if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
                            conn.Close();
                        }
                    }

                    return results;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
```

I can't retrieve my data in my database even though I have no error in my code behind.

Is there a problem with my connection string? I don't have a password in my ms sql server though. Is this the correct code of connection string? Please Help.

```
//ConnectionString for accessing into MSSql
connector.ConnectionString = "SERVER=KEITH;UID=KEITH/LaurenceKeith;Password=;DATABASE=Student;";
```

Comment: Why are you putting the connection string in the code behind?? I think it belongs in the web.config.

Comment: It doesn't HAVE to go there @frenchie, but it does make it easier to change connection strings if your moving servers IE: test to production.

Comment: Can you connect to the database using SQL management studio?

Comment: Yes I can connect to the sql management studio but getting the connection string. I can't actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as connection string, will use Windows Authentication for login.

```
connector.ConnectionString = "data source=KEITH;initial catalog=Student;Integrated Security=SSPI;providerName=System.Data.SqlClient";
```

This is assuming Keith is your SQL server and the database is Student

Comment: It does not work, I think there's a problem with my query, cause I want to display my data when the web page loads at start up. Sorry first time learning aspx here.

Comment: You need to pass your query to your ExecuteQuery method, like ExecuteQuery(query). Not sure why you are running 2 queries right after eachother either. Can you just do select * from Student where StudentID = 2011017997' AND Password=lalbano";

Comment: hello Dylan, I think there's an error in your connectionstring, I think providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"; should be providerName=System.Data.SqlClient"; because there's an open quotation already after ConnectionString = "